# add vimeo tab to facebook (company) page

Tags: facebook, vimeo, facebook-page

I recently authored a company page on facebook. The company page is for a design firm and they have a bunch of videos on Vimeo.

Can someone please guide me on how to add a separate tab on the left side for vimeo and have facebook poll in my videos/activity from vimeo ?

I'm doing this for the first time, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to build a custom tab (you just create an app on Facebook, put a URL of your site in the Tab URL field, install the app to your Page, and the tab will just iframe the URL you specified) or find a tab that does what you want on a site such as [Appbistro](http://appbistro.com/products/home). If you can't find what you're looking for and don't have the technical resources to build it yourself, you may want to contact one of our [Preferred Developer Consultants](https://developers.facebook.com/preferreddevelopers/) who can help you build what you're looking for.

Comment: Vimeo is a very popular video service, so I'd assume there is a facebook app for that. Would you be able to give me a link to the verified app ?

Comment: I don't think Vimeo makes an official one. Looks like a bunch of people including some of my friends who do Facebook Page consulting use [this one](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=102076423177195).

Comment: quick question: Is it required by me to give the app access to my profile page ? Can I not just give it access to the page I created ?

Comment: @brainydexter - You give it permission as an admin of the page. Pages cannot give the permission by themselves.